# Javascript - Call function within object's method bind 'this' to global object

Tags: javascript, scope, this

All the articles and books I read say that it doesn't matter where I define my function, it's where I invoke the function that decides which object 'this' is bound to. But with this example, I don't understand why 'this' is bound to global object.

```
    function foo(){
        console.log(this);
    }
    var obj = {
        myMethod: function() {
            foo();
        }
    };
    obj.myMethod();
```

As I understand, 'obj' object is the one that invokes the function so 'this' should be bound to 'obj', but the result is window object. Can anyone please explain this for me?

Comment: What matters is *how* you invoke a function, not *where*.

Comment: You say: "All the articles and books I read say [...]" - It would be great if you add some of the links and quotations (including the title) from the books to your post.

Comment: "To understand this binding, we have to understand the call-site: the location in code where a function is called (not where it's declared)" - You don't know JS ebook page 172

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling `foo` from within `myMethod`, so it isn't `obj` directly calling `foo`. To have `this` point to `obj` you should assign `foo` directly to `myMethod`.

e.g.

```js
function foo() {
  console.log(this);
}
var obj = {
  myMethod: foo
};
obj.myMethod();
```

Answer (score 2):

`this` is a strange beast in JavaScript, so you'd do well to read the [overview on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

But in summary, it doesn't matter where the function was originally defined, but what does matter is the location from which it's being executed...

1. If the function is defined globally and you invoke it using `myFunction(x)`, then it's executing in the global scope, and `this` will refer to the global object (as you have discovered in your `foo()` function where `this` is the Window object)
2. If a function is contained in an object's property then `this` will refer to the object that contains the property.  (Object properties which contain functions are called "methods")

For example...

```
myFunction = function() { console.log(this); }
myObject = {
  myMethod: myFunction
}

myFunction(x) // `this` == the global window object.
myObject.myMethod(x) // `this` == `myObject`
```

NOTE 1. You can also invoke functions using 'call', 'apply', and 'bind' 
which enable you to specify what `this` should refer to inside the function when it runs.  (Read about them in detail on the link I provided.)

NOTE 2. The ES6 "arrow function" syntax (`(x)=>{ ... }`) is an exception, as `this` will always be the same value as `this` would be wherever the arrow function itself was defined.

Comment: It does not matter *where* you define a function. What matters only is how you invoke it.

Comment: The OP's understanding is "it doesn't matter where I define my function, it's where I invoke the function that decides which object 'this' is bound to.", which is not strictly true.  The value of ```this``` is (generally) the object where the function is defined, so in that sense it matters very much where you define the function.

Comment: "The value of this is (generally) the object where the function is defined" --- that's not true. It does not matter where the function was initially defined. It's still only matters how you invoke: https://jsfiddle.net/n3drh9nh/ https://jsfiddle.net/v8v32e7b/

Comment: Okay, yes "where it's initially defined" doesn't matter.  I was describing the location of a method property as "where it's defined".  You are referring to that as "how it's executed" (by which I first thought you meant call, apply, etc.)  So, I think I've found the happy medium with least ambiguity for the OP.  I'll update the answer again :-)

Answer (score 1):

When foo() is created it is created with a closure . When it is invoked it still remembers its scope through this closure with which it was created and at that time, this was bound to global object.